# How to calculate SD, SEM, IC95 of a ratio?

Tags: standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics, ratio

I feel like this question has been asked a billion times but none of the answers I read seem to fit my situation, so sorry if it's redundant and I missed it !

Here's my situation :

I have 2 non-paired groups, A and B

- 13 individuals each
- Continuous variable
- Normal distribution (based on shapiro test)

I want to compare those two groups and see if there is a difference, so I went for a Student test which yield this result :

```
Welch Two Sample t-test

p-value = 0.001857
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  2.845288 10.861379
sample estimates:
mean of A mean of B 
 13.05333   6.20000
```

So that's great, there's a statistically significative difference between my two groups and I can use the given mean to get that the difference is 6.8533 CI95(2.845, 10.86).

Now, I've been talking with my boss who ask me for a ratio rather than a difference. Again, easy to do, I just divide mean A by mean B, and we get

ratio A/B = 2.1 meaning that group A has 2.1 times more XYZ than group B, easy to understand and to visualize

But from there, I have no idea how I'm supposed to get an SD, SEM or CI for this ratio.

I've seen someone post this link, but note that I'm neither a classicaly trained statistician, even less a mathematician so I don't understand a thing of it =/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Means_and_variances_of_random_ratios

If any of you have an (hopefully easy to understand) answer, I would be so grateful

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can get into unexpected problems with the ratio of two random variables: it is unlikely that the mean of the ratio is the ratio of the means, and if the distributions really are normally distributed the mean of the ratios may not even exist - from your link $\mathbb E[1/Y]$ is generally not $1/\mathbb E[Y]$ and worse is undefined for any distribution with positive probability or density around $0$.